# Google Edge Cache not works for my custom domain by HTTPS in Google App Engine application

Tags: google-app-engine, caching, https

In Google App Engine application (Node.js) I uses next cache headers:

- cache-control: "public, max-age=90"
- pragma: "Public"

When I doing request by HTTP all works great and with caching:

- Response time: 33 ms
- New lifetime cache header in response (ie Age: 24)

When I doing request by HTTPS cache does't works:

- Response time: 466 ms
- No any lifetime cache headers in response

Addition info:

- `http://project-id.appspot.com` - works fine
- `https://project-id.appspot.com` - works fine
- `http://custom-domain.com` - works fine
- `https://custom-domain.com` - not cached

How can I enable the cache for HTTPS? 
Is there a problem with the settings?

Comment: Sometimes you may have to hit the same request a few times in a row before it starts caching at the edge.

Comment: Thank you, but I already made a large number of requests. And the situation is still the same. Requests meet all requirements from https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/caching